# How to build JPA Predicate for checking point belongs to given polygon

Tags: java, sql, jpa, hibernate-spatial, jpa-criteria

I'm trying to build `javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate` which determines is point belongs to a given polygon.

That predicate I want to use to build the query. I want to use Criteria API to dynamically build queries on given params from a dto.

```
import org.geolatte.geom.codec.Wkt;
import org.hibernate.spatial.predicate.JTSSpatialPredicates;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Predicate;

public List<EComparable> searchByParams(SearchFormDto searchFormDto) {
    var cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    var query = cb.createQuery(EComparable.class);
    var root = query.from(EComparable.class);
    Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[10];
    predicates[0] = JTSSpatialPredicates.contains(
            cb,
            Wkt.fromWkt("POLYGON ((10 10, 10 20, 20 20, 20 15, 10 10))"), // Hardcoded for test, will be given from dto
            root.get("geom").type() // I'm really not shure about that part too
    );
    // predicates[...] = ...
    query.select(root).where(predicates);
    var resultList = entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList();
    return resultList;
}
```

So I found `JTSSpatialPredicates`, but can't understand how to adopt it.

### The problem with arguments:

That class provides only two variants for `contains`:

(..., Expression, Expression)

```
org.hibernate.spatial.predicate.JTSSpatialPredicates#contains(javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder, javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<? extends org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry>, javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<? extends org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry>)
```

Or
(..., Expression, Geometry)

```
org.hibernate.spatial.predicate.JTSSpatialPredicates#contains(javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder, javax.persistence.criteria.Expression<? extends org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry>, org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry)
```

But I need as understood (..., Geometry, Expression). Given polygon contains point from `geom` column.

## How to figure it out?

---

`geom` is the column name in which point location stored (db type `geometry`).

Needed to select all rows which belongs to given polygon and do some additional filtering.

Env: Java 16, Spring Boot, Hibernate, Postgis, Postgresql.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to wrap geometry into an expression via `literal` and change a bit 2nd arg too:

```
import org.locationtech.jts.geom.Geometry;
import org.locationtech.jts.io.WKTReader;

//...

predicates[0] = JTSSpatialPredicates.contains(
        cb,
        cb.literal(wktReader.read("POLYGON ((0 0, 0 70, 70 70, 70 0, 0 0))")),
        root.get("geom").as(Geometry.class)
);
```